# Binding to a class extending ObservableCollection breaks notifications

Tags: c#, wpf

In my application I have a class that extends `ObservableCollection` for a specific type in order to simplify adding/removing items from it:

```
public class ObservableCollectionICadObjectInfo : ObservableCollection<ICadObjectInfo>
{
    public void AddUnique(ICadObjectInfo value)
    {
        List<ICadObjectInfo> matches = Items.Where(i => i.FullName == value.FullName).ToList();
        if (matches.Count == 0)
        {
            Items.Add(value);
        }
    }

    public void AddRangeUnique(List<ICadObjectInfo> values)
    {
        foreach (ICadObjectInfo value in values)
        {
            AddUnique(value);
        }
    }

    public void RemoveItem(ICadObjectInfo item)
    {
        if (item == null) { return; }
        ICadObjectInfo match = Items.Where(i => i.FullName == item.FullName).FirstOrDefault();
        if (match is not null)
        {
            Items.Remove(match);
        }
    }
}
```

An instance of this class is used in the following ModelView that serves as a `DataContext` for a `ListBox` binding:

```
public class CadObjectSelectorViewModel : ObservableClass
{
    private ObservableCollectionICadObjectInfo _cadObjects;
    private ICadObjectInfo _selectedObject;
    public ObservableCollectionICadObjectInfo CadObjects { get { return _cadObjects; } set { _cadObjects = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CadObjects)); }  }
    public ICadObjectInfo SelectedObject { get { return _selectedObject; } set { _selectedObject = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedObject)); } }

    public CadObjectSelectorViewModel(ObservableCollectionICadObjectInfo cadObjects)
    {
        this.CadObjects = cadObjects;
    }
}

<ListBox x:Name="CadObjectsListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CadObjects}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedObject}"/>
```

Now, if I update the items in the list (clear them, or add new items), `ListBox.Items` updates, but for whatever reason the `ListBox` itself does not, and still shows previous data:

[image]

Weirder still, if I clear the list, initially nothing happens, but if I leave the application to run idle for 10-40 seconds (during which it is responsive), the `ListBox` finally updates. Sometimes it happens sooner, sometimes later. It's almost like some GC cycle nudges the `ListBox` and makes it realize it is empty. Adding new items to this `ListBox` does not make it update no matter how long I wait though.

And if I do not use `ObservableCollectionICadObjectInfo` in my `CadObjectSelectorViewModel`, but instead declare `CadObjects` as `ObservableCollection<ICadObjectInfo>`, the issue completely disappears, everything updates immediately.

Why does using this extended `ObservableCollection` class cause this issue? I read through the documentation and did a proper search before asking this question, but I can't seem to find anything relevant.

Comment: FWIW you can use `.Any()` instead of `.ToList()` and `.Count()` to determine if an element already exists with the collection. You'll save yourself some allocations.

Comment: @jhmckimm Thank you for that suggestion, but would that really work if my intention is not allow objects with identical properties into this list, even if they are separate and distinct objects?

Comment: yes. You retain the `.Where()` call, but replace `.ToList()` with `.Any()` (which returns a bool - `true` if anything satisfies the predicate in your where clause).

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Comment: You could even drop the Where call and just write `if (!this.Any(i => i.FullName == value.FullName)) { Add(value); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call your updates through the inner collection's update functions, call them through the `ObservableCollection`'s:

```
public void AddUnique(ICadObjectInfo value)
{
    List<ICadObjectInfo> matches = Items.Where(i => i.FullName == value.FullName).ToList();
    if (matches.Count == 0)
    {
        Add(value);   // <----
    }
}

public void RemoveItem(ICadObjectInfo item)
{
    if (item == null) { return; }
    ICadObjectInfo match = Items.Where(i => i.FullName == item.FullName).FirstOrDefault();
    if (match is not null)
    {
        Remove(match);  // <----
    }
}
```

Though just to be clear, your approach is absolutely horrendous. The fact that you managed to break something as basic as `ObservableCollection` should be ringing very loud alarm bells in your mind, or at the very least in your managers'. I would strongly reconsider this mess and try to understand what you're trying to achieve here.

If it's a collection that doesn't have duplicates, you failed because you can just directly call `Add`, thus breaking that promise. If it's a collection with helper functions to only add if elements aren't present, you have extension methods for that. If it's a collection that's simply used to display the data without repetitions, well, don't get the repetitions in the first place. If you can't figure that out, then use either a `CollectionView`, or a converter.

No matter how you cut it, the approach in your question has no place other than to confuse people and break code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and critique. Calling Add and other calls directly solves the issue. The idea here is that this collection must not have any duplicates. The check is done through FullName property to prevent a ICadObjectInfo object to be added to this collection if it's properties match an existing object in this collection, even if they are two distinct objects. If the current implementation is bad for this intent, what should I be doing instead?

Comment: Something like [this](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYCMBYAUKgBgAJVMA6AYQHsAbGgUwGNgBLKqAZzIHkAjAKybAAslTj0aAbjx4MRAKpQWARwj0+HemABuAQ14NqdIWygAeACoA+IiCIateg/SMNmpy1bwBvPEX9EAA5gVMBC9HBEVNpaYCziJAAsRACSnFrAKWEAtgAULFDARAXiAB4wRBbFOQCUfgG+uAHNxQBmuVn02VxpZdztLLVEALzDRAC0mHVNLbO8uppkaZpgmTn5UGUVg1010jP+AL54x7iymABsJOhEAAo+9f6kV6jJwroFudPNjbP+emAiIwRkQoPQAO4KJSqdS8FZOQy0NysdhmUgELwHFq/P7NABEujxFTxjCJRDxvDJBKpcCppMeLUO+1xDOarSoYHoukYAAtcgDql1ilAgd9cQFSABOfK1ZkBU6HIA) will get you much closer, but it's still not perfect.

Comment: The actual answer is to figure out why you have duplicates in the first place when you don't want them, and simply not have duplicates from the beginning. Or if it's just for displaying in views, as I said, use converters to filter them out.

Comment: Thanks for that example. I do actually need to not have duplicates, it's not just for displaying. I am not sure how else I can "simply not have duplicates from the beginning". If I do the duplicate check outside the ObservableCollection or it's derivatives when adding new items, then the check can be circumvented by accessing ObservableCollection.Add directly, without the check. The only solution I can think of is to use a wrapper for that collection, make it private, and expose it's methods manually through the wrapper, adding a duplicate check where needed. That can't be right either.

Comment: "then the check can be circumvented by accessing ObservableCollection.Add directly" that's only if you expose the full observable collection as public. It sounds like in your case you shouldn't, you should just expose [the read only part of it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.readonlyobservablecollection-1?view=net-7.0). These are all solved problems since .Net 3.0, 15 years ago.

Comment: "I am not sure how else I can "simply not have duplicates from the beginning"" -- to be clear, duplicates don't randomly materialize in your structures. I find that beginners often have trouble with this concept: if something happens, you explicitly wrote it, computers don't do anything you don't tell them to. So either don't expose a way to add duplicates from the outside (which you did in your original example), or take control of the code that inserts items and make sure you don't insert duplicates.